Why is the output type bool in this OCaml fun?
I'm sure I'm missing something, but where is the bool?
let iter t ~f = 
  let rec loop !t  = function
    |Some element -> ~f element.value; loop element.next
    |None -> () 

Expecting unit, have bool in type of iter:
('a element option -> unit) ref -> f:('a -> 'b) -> bool
Also compared to this version
let iter t ~f = 
  let rec loop   = function

    |Some element -> f element.value; loop element.next
    |None -> () 

in loop !t

Why 'a element option ref vs. ('a element option -> unit)?

Ignoring the first part because it's not valid code, if we look at the second but:
let iter t ~f = 
  let rec loop = function
    | None -> ()
    | Some element ->
        f element.value;
        loop element.next 
  in 
  loop !t

Then t can be inferred to have type 'a ekoption ref because we use the under operator ! on it. We pass this dereference value to loop which pattern matches it against the constructors Some and None so now we know we're dealing with a ref of an option type.
But we access fields that are unique to a presumed element type defined as:
type 'a element = { 
  value : 'a;
  next : 'a element option
}

So now we know t is of type 'a element option ref. If you want to change the type to your expected one, simply change one character and not dereference t.
let iter t ~f = 
  let rec loop = function
    | None -> ()
    | Some element ->
        f element.value;
        loop element.next
  in 
  loop t


Your first example is not valid OCaml code, so it's hard to say much about it. Since it's not valid code, it doesn't have a type. I don't see a way to fix it up other than to change it to the second example :-)
Problems with the first example:

!t is invalid syntax for a parameter name
A function named loop is defined but never called

